# менять только один символ в replace js

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var datedr = $('#dob').val();
var dr = replace.datedr('-','');
console.log(dr.replace('-',''));    
$('#rtec_custom2').val($('#razryad_new').val());
$('#rtec_custom3').val($('#medid').val());
$('#rtec_other').val($('#dob').val());
$('#rtec_custom1').val($('#vesovaya').val());
$('#rtec_custom4').val($('#trenerje').val());
$('#rtec_first').val($('#fionew').val());
});
</script>
```

стоит задача заменить - на . в дате (#dob) и поставить его вместо #rtec_other
Формат даты как вы поняли 0000-00-00, а надо 0000.00.00, как это можно быстро сделать? При первом replace почему то выдает 0000.00-00, хотел еще одну поставить, но там уже ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для замены всех вхождений, используйте регулярное выражение с флагом `g`:

```js
$('#dob').on('input', function() {
  console.log('Исходная строка:', this.value);
  console.log('Строка после замены:', this.value.replace(/-/g, '.'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="dob">
```